# Mix does not show the current contract state

Tags: solidity, mix

I encouter little problems using mix.
I have the following contract-code:

```
contract C {
    function C() {}

    struct S {
        address creator;
    }

    mapping(string => S) M;
    uint x;

    function set(string _hash) {
        S memory N = S({
            creator : msg.sender
        });

        M[_hash] = N; //I dont see the mapping in Mix
        x = _hash; //I see 'x' in the current state with the correct value
    }

    function get(string _hash) returns (address addr) {
        return M[_hash].creator;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I do not see the current state of the contract in the bottom right corner of the IDE. While I see `x` and the value of `_hash`, I do not see the state of the `mapping(string => S)`, which should be in the variable `M`

I thought the `mapping` maybe is just empty after calling, but when I call the `get`-function, It returns the correct address from the sender before.

Does anyone had the same issue before or can help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Mappings work by hashing the key to get the storage address and so the keys themselves aren't stored.  Unless keys can be provided, such as in a seperate lookup table, there is no simple way to view the contents of a mapping so Mix simply doesn't show them.